# What is the probability of recapturing a specified number of tagged elk?

Tags: probability

Question:
Elk dwell in a certain forest. There are $N$ elk, of which a simple random sample of
size $n$ are captured and tagged. The captured elk are returned to the population, and then a new sample is drawn, this time with size $m$. This is an important method that is widely used
in ecology, known as capture-recapture. What is the probability that exactly $k$ of the $m$
elk in the new sample were previously tagged? (Assume that an elk that was captured
before doesn’t become more or less likely to be captured again.)

My answer is

$$\binom{m}{k}(n/N)^k(1-n/N)^{m-k}$$

but the answer in the text book is
$$\frac{\binom{n}{k}\times \binom{N-n}{m-k} }{\binom{N}{m}}$$

I want to know why my answer is wrong.

Comment: Well...your events are not independent.  Knowing that a given elk was in both samples changes the probabilities for the other elk.

Comment: Your answer is in the form of a binomial probability, the textbook answer is in the form of a hypergeometric probability. loosely speaking, the former assumes you are sampling with replacement whereas the hypergeometric assumes you are sampling without replacement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Naive probability question - why is my method wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792348/naive-probability-question-why-is-my-method-wrong)  Note: @XanderHenderson 's answer below is better than the answer at the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

As in the question, assume that a total of $n$ elk are tagged, $m$ are recaptured, and $k$ of those $m$ recaptured elk are tagged.
Assume that $m,n > k$.  Otherwise, the probability is zero (e.g. it is impossible to capture $k$ tagged elk if only $n<k$ have been tagged in the first place).

#### Probability with replacement

The answer you gave would be correct if the second sample were being taken *with replacement*.  That is, if your procedure is

1. capture and tag $n$ elk from a population of $N$,
2. return those $n$ elk to the environment,
3. capture one elk, check if it is tagged, and return it to the environment, and
4. repeat step 3 $m$ times.

In this procedure, each elk caught in step 3 is independent of the previous steps.  So, for example, you could capture the same elk over and over and over again.  The first expression in the question comes from the observation that the probability of recapturing a tagged elk is $n/N$, and the probability of capturing an untagged elk is $(N-n)/N = 1 - n/N$.  So, for example, the probability that the first elk is tagged, the next $m-k$ have not, and the last $k-1$ have been tagged is
$$ \left( \frac{n}{N} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{n}{N} \right)^{m-k} \left( \frac{n}{N} \right)^{k-1} = \left( \frac{n}{N} \right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{n}{N} \right)^{m-k}. $$
Indeed, the probability of choosing any *particular* sequence of captured elk where $k$ of them have been tagged is
$$ \left( \frac{n}{N} \right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{n}{N} \right)^{m-k}. $$
But order doesn't matter, and there are $\binom{m}{k}$ ways of arranging a sequence of $m$ elk such that $k$ have been tagged, hence the final probability (with replacement) is
$$ \binom{m}{k} \left( \frac{n}{N} \right)^k \left( 1 - \frac{n}{N} \right)^{m-k}. $$

#### Probability without replacement

The procedure described in the problem seems to describe taking the second sample *without* replacement.  That is, the procedure is

1. capture and tag $n$ elk from a population of $N$,
2. return those $n$ elk to the environment, then
3. capture a total of $m$ elk, count the number that have been previously tagged, and return the elk to the environment.

In this case, there are a total of $\binom{N}{m}$ different ways of capturing $m$ elk from a population of $N$.  The goal is to determine how many of these different samples have exactly $k$ tagged elk (thus this will be the denominator in the probability).

I think that the easiest way to understand this is to imagine a two step process.  To obtain a sample of $m$ elk, exactly $k$ of which are tagged,

- choose $k$ of the tagged elk, and then
- choose $m-k$ of the untagged elk.

There are a total of $n$ tagged elk, so there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways of choosing $k$ of them.  There are $N-n$ untagged elk, so there are $\binom{N-n}{m-k}$ ways of choosing $m-k$ of them.  Thus there are a total of
$$ \binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{m-k} $$
ways of obtaining a sample of $m$ elk, exactly $k$ of which are tagged.  Thus the *probability* of obtaining a sample of $m$ elk, exactly $k$ of which are tagged, is the total number of ways of obtaining such a sample, divided by the total number of samples of $m$ elk.  Thus the probability is
$$ \frac{\binom{n}{k} \binom{N-n}{m-k}}{\binom{N}{m}}. $$

Comment: NB: This feels like the kind of question which should have already been answered here.  However, after some searching for posts which discuss choosing a sample without replacement, I cannot find a reasonable dupe target.  If someone else finds one, please ping me, and I will close this question and delete my answer.

Comment: I doubt that an answer to a duplicate (if one is found) will be better than yours here, so please leave it up even in that case. In fact it is a duplicate. This one's even about the same elk population, linked in the related questions column: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792348/naive-probability-question-why-is-my-method-wrong?rq=1